# Using prismJs in an angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use the [PrismJs](http://prismjs.com/)  in my angular app

On the left you see what I'm getting, on the right you have the expected result
[image: screenshot]

Below you can see the code that I'm using for it.
here is the directive I'm using:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function prism() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                element.ready(function () {
                    Prism.highlightElement(element[0].querySelector('code'));
                });
            }
        };
    }

    angular.module('app.directives').directive('prism', prism);

})();
```

Anyone any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Alright found out my problem, appreantly tags arn't escaped, so adding that did fix it!